# Would an Islamic Bank Account be preferable to a Jew?

Tags: avodah-zarah, money, business, islam, lending-interest-ribbis

[Islamic bank accounts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_banking_and_finance) do not involve interest or fees for loans of money and prevents the bank from investing your money in various questionable businesses, like the pork and sex industries.

Would it be preferable for a Jew to have such a bank account rather than a regular account?

Does it matter that the account's label evokes association to another religion?

Comment: How is the pork industry "questionable" from a Jewish point of view?

Comment: @IsaacMoses A Jew isn't allowed to engage in it. Maybe having money in a bank that invests in that is problematic too...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37165/discussion-between-n-and-ray).

Answer (score 2):

If by "A regular bank" you mean another non-Jewish bank, then according to some poskim it is preferable to charge interest when lending money to a non-Jew, rather than to give him an interest-free loan.
Thus, a regular non-Jewish bank which pays interest on deposits would be preferable to a non-Jewish bank which does not pay interest.

Comment: Can you name some of these poskim? As I commented on another of your answer, MY loves sources to make answers stronger. Welcome again!

Comment: If Hebrew sources work for you SEE THIS LINK:                        https://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=35186

Comment: It is not for me - it is for all current and future readers. Best is to edit your answer and add to it rather than leave important content in the comments. Thanks !