# Is it forbidden to buy stock of an American bank?

Tags: halacha, lending-interest-ribbis

Is it forbidden to buy stock of an American bank? The reason I ask is given the number of Jews in the USA, it seems unlikely that the bank wouldn't lend money with interest to Jews. What is the halacha on this and what is the stingent opinion?

Comment: "What is the [stringent] opinion?" Well, as most things in Judaism have a wide range of opinions, almost all situations would have an opinion that says 'completely forbidden in all circumstances'. But in practice, things are usually a bit more nuanced than that...

Comment: We need [RibbisRabbiAndMore](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/17314/ribbisrabbiandmore)!

Comment: Short version: a Jew can both borrow and lend money on interest to and from a non-Jew. If the bank is owned by a Jew, they probably know about these kinds of issues and have what’s called a *heter iska* written up, which rephrases the loan in terms of a business venture and thereby skirts the ribbis issues (doesn’t work in many cases but could potentially apply here).

Comment: related: [Corporations, Jewish Shareholders and Interest](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45381/corporations-jewish-shareholders-and-interest) and [Would an Islamic Bank Account be preferable to a Jew?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69465/11501)